# Ошибка при чтении, необработанное исключение и нарушение прав доступа

Tags: c++, исключения, обработка-ошибок

В головном модуле ввести  массив строк. Строк не более пятнадцати, длина строки  не более восьмидесяти знаков. В первой функции, используя массив указателей на строки, осуществить ввод строк. Во второй функции найти строку, содержащую слово с наибольшим количеством знаков (самое длинное слово).

```
   #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void Ent(char arr[80])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the words: \n";
        cin.getline(arr, 80);
    }
}

int Max(char arr[80], size_t max = 0)
{
    char *strToken;
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        strtok(&arr[j], " ");
        while (strToken != NULL)
        {
            max = max < strlen(strToken) ? strlen(strToken) : max; //ошибка тут

            strToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        std::cout << max << std::endl;

        return 0;

}

void main()
{
    char arr[80];
    size_t max = 0;
    int sw;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "1 - enter, 2 - max char";
        cin >> sw;
        switch (sw)
        {
         case 1: Ent(arr);
            break;
         case 2: Max(arr, max);
             break;

        }
    }
}
```

В 21 строке ошибка при чтении, а в 23 строке ошибку при компилировании: 
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x0F53FBA0 (ucrtbased.dll) в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: 1) Если есть ошибка компиляции то не может быть ошибки выполнения (потому как код несобрался), и наоборот если код собрался то ошибки компиляции нету. 2)Думаю люди здесь до 21 все умеют считать, но лучше всётаки наглядно в комментарии написать `/*тут ошибка1*/`

Comment: Я очень сильно подозреваю, что текст ошибки компиляции прямо указывает на проблему. И в подобных вопросах ее следует обязательно приводить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, ваши слеты легко объяснить...

Чтоб компилировалось, вспомните, что комментарий начинается с `//`, а не с `\\`.

Чтоб не слетало - не используйте неинициализированный указатель `strToken` - вы явно забыли дописать его в

```
strToken = strtok(&arr[j], " ");
```

Но вот будет ли программа работать после этих исправлений - это уже другой вопрос... Который вы вскоре зададите.

Потому что вы создали на все 15 строк один массив, пишете все в него, перезаписывая ранее введенное, а в `Max` просто одну и ту же строку мучаете, начиная с разных букв. Это так, намек, поразбираться самостоятельно, прежде чем спрашивать :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы явно хотели написать

```
strToken = strtok(&arr[j], " ");
```

но забыли присваивание. Поэтому `strToken` у вас осталась неинициализированной и указывает непонятно куда (а конкретно она содержит адрес `0xCCCCCCCC`). Поэтому `strlen(strToken)` у вас вызывает ошибку доступа к памяти.